# Is it possible to monitor login activity on mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, android-permissions

For example, is it possible to give a native app permission to monitor how many failed login attempts were made to the device itself in real time? Alternatively, are there logs an app could poll for that information?

I haven't found a good place to see what permissions are available to developers for building native apps. The best I have found is [this list](https://gist.github.com/Arinerron/1bcaadc7b1cbeae77de0263f4e15156f) of permissions for Android.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are thinking of corporate owned devices rather than consumer, look into: [Android for Work - Enterprise Mobile Management APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements) or [Apple Mobile Device Management](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement) Note that I'm doubtful that any third-party app can capture the number of failed login device attempts, however you should be able to set policy for wiping a device if too many bad password attempts are made. Alternatively you may need root or a Custom ROM/extension which provides that info.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by setting up [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjaKnhsSs6gIVEbwYCh1grwTtEAAYASABEgL9J_D_BwE&platform=android). Then you can log login button clicks and log successes/failures etc.

Comment: That's a good idea for login attempts to the app. I meant monitoring login attempts to the actual device. I've updated my question to be clearer.